# why does my function prevent other values from being retrieved when the date picker value is retrieved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, modal-dialog

Basically, when the datepicker value is set, and the function called, the function returns the string of the datepicker value but the id is blank.

When the datepicker is not set, and the function called, the function returns the ID.

Datepicker and input in the MODAL

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>AUDIT ID:</label>
 <input class="form-control"   id="auditid" type="text" disabled=""></input>    
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label>Date of Audit :</label>
  <div class="input-group date" >
    <div class="input-group-addon" >
       <i class="fa fa-calendar" ></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker27" >
  </div>
  <!-- /.input group -->
 </div>
```

Function call

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="settargetdate()" >Set Target Date</button>
```

Function itself

```
function settargetdate() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#AUDITMODAL').modal('hide')
  }, 3)
  $('#submitting').show();
  var IDAUD = document.getElementById("auditid").value;
  var datewa = document.getElementById("datepicker27").value;;

  alert(IDAUD + datewa);
}
```

Comment: im still confused

Comment: The function doesn't have a `return` statement, how can it return anything? And you're not doing anything with the return value anyway. Are you talking about the alert?

Comment: `</input>` is not needed. `<input>` elements are self-closing.

Comment: By return I mean it gives a value when called. That's pretty simple   looking at the code ?

Comment: Basically, if I enter a value in the datepicker, and call the function settargetdate() I expect a value for ID and Date as in the alert, however I only get the value for the value from the datepicker and not the ID. However when I fail to enter any value for the datepicker, and call the function, I get the value for the ID. Weird right ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, when the datepicker is triggered, it resets the modal which makes the id field empty. This was a bug and was solved using the following code from this link : [why does bootstrap-datepicker trigger 'show.bs.modal' when it is displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113228/why-does-bootstrap-datepicker-trigger-show-bs-modal-when-it-is-displayed)

```
$("#my-datepicker").datepicker().on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    // prevent datepicker from firing bootstrap modal "show.bs.modal"
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```